# Stop main thread and show progress dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

hello guys i am having an async task where i get points from online , depending on these points i must decide which popup window i should show on main thread . for example if points are less i should show "Buy points" screen else show "Buy item" screen .I also want to show progressdialog until points are loaded

if i do this the main thread stops until points are loaded but progress dialog won't show up

```
   String str_result= new Jsontask().execute("my url" + uid).get();
```

if i do this progress dialog shows but points loaded are wrong

```
 new Jsontask().execute("my url" + uid);
```

my async taks

```
 class Jsontask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog  pdia;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       pdia = new ProgressDialog(PopupActivity.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading...");
        pdia.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    // get my points here

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        System.out.println(result);
        setRewardpoints(Integer.parseInt(result));
         pdia.dismiss();
    }

}
```

how can i show progressdialog and stop main thread from executing until async task is complete?

Comment: Why you want to stop main thread? You shouldn't.. lock UI with a ProgressDialog is enough

Comment: i want to stop until async task is complete so i can get correct points and launch correct popup window

Comment: why dont you show the progress dialog in the pnPostExecute after you dismiss the pdia?

Comment: You don't want to stop main thread, otherwise your application will be closed. You have to work in onPostExecute method to show a new progress dialog or give a look to onProgressUpdate method.

Comment: after i start async task i check condition for points on my main thread and launch popup window, it is taking about 6-7 seconds for point to load on async task , so i want wait for these 6-7 seconds so poins loaded are correct and i want to show progress dialog for these 6-7 seconds , is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Redman So, You get that control in onPostExecute Method. After you successfully get points in doInBackground method, control reaches  onPostExecute Method. Put your control for showing pop up there.

Comment: ya just did that , it works fine but i had to put a huge code inside onPostExecute method :)

Answer (score 1):

you should create a new `interface` which will contains a callback method this method you will call it in the `postExecute` method giving it as a parameter the number of points returned

```
public interface jsonTaskCallback{
  public void pointsProcessing(int point);}
```

now you should create a new property from the `interface` in the `JsonTask` class and add new Constructor which has as a parameter a `JsonTAskCallback` variable.

```
JsonTaskCallBack taskCallBack;    
public JsonTask(JsonTaskCallBack taskCallBack){
           this.taskCallBack = taskCallBack;
}
```

after that call the `JsonTaskCallBack$pointsPrecessing` method in the `postExecute` method, after that use this statement:

```
 new Jsontask(new JsonTaskCallback(){
      @Override
      public void pointsProcessing(int point){
           // proccess the result and show the convenient popup window
        }
 }).execute("my url" + uid);
```